# Understanding synchronized blocks and intrinsic locks

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm just studied the topics of `synchronized` methods and blocks. I don't entirely understand synchronized blocks. For example:

```
synchronized(dataStructure){
    someDataStructure.modifyInSomeWay();
}
```

Here's what I think this code does: it tells threads that before they can run `someDataStructure.modifyInSomeWay()`, they need to obtain the intrinsic lock of `dataStructure`. Is this correct?

If it is, what about the next assumption: a thread needs an object's intrinsic lock *only* when trying to access a member synchronized method, or a synchronized block referencing the object. In any other case, a thread doesn't need the object's lock in order to mess with it in any way.

If both of my assumptions are correct, than that means that the above code actually says the following:

> "A thread can only run this piece of code once it obtained the
>   intrinsic lock of `dataStructure`. The intrinsic lock of
>   `dataStructure` is currently owned by another thread only if one of
>   the following is true:
>
> A- A thread is currently running a `synchornized` method in
>   `dataStructure`.
>
> B- A thread is currently running a `synchronized` block referencing
>   `dataStructure`.
>
> In any other case, for example when a thread is simply messing with
>   `dataStructure`'s state, the intrinsic lock is free."

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 2):

> it tells threads that before they can run
>   `someDataStructure.modifyInSomeWay()`, they need to obtain the intrinsic
>   lock of dataStructure. Is this correct?

Yes. The thread will block until it acquires the lock.

> a thread needs an object's intrinsic lock only when trying to access a
>   member synchronized method, or a synchronized block referencing the
>   object.

Anytime you see `synchronized`, the lock for some object needs to be acquired for execution to continue. Which object depends on the use of `synchronized`. In a `static` method, it is the declaring class's `Class` object. In an instance method, it is the object on which the method is invoked. In a `synchronized (..)` block, it is the object referenced by the expression in `(..)`.

> "A thread can only run this piece of code once it obtained the 
>   intrinsic lock of dataStructure. The intrinsic lock of dataStructure
>   is currently owned by another thread only if one of the following is
>   true:
>
> A- A thread is currently running a synchronized method in dataStructure.
>
> B- A thread is currently running a synchronized block referencing dataStructure.
>
> In any other case, for example when a thread is simply messing with dataStructure's 
>   state, the intrinsic lock is free."

It is unclear what you mean by *messing with dataStructure's state* in that last sentence. If you mean simply interacting with the object outside of any `synchronized` context (on the object), then yes. Note that even if you had `synchronized` on an object with thread A, thread B could still use the non synchronized methods of the same object without blocking.

But A (assuming an instance method) and B are correct.

Comment: By 'is free' he means the opposite of 'is currently owned by another thread'.